# t-test using OpenCPU

Tags: javascript, r, statistics, opencpu

I tried to use t-test in R using OpenCPU as follows -

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.opencpu.org/opencpu-0.4.js"></script>
```

and

```
ocpu.seturl("//public.opencpu.org/ocpu/library/stats/R")

var x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
var y = [7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];
// call R function: stats::t.test
var req = ocpu.rpc("t.test",{
    "x" : x,
    "y" : y
}, function(output){
    alert("t.test equals: " + output);
});

//optional
req.fail(function(){
    alert("R returned an error: " + req.responseText);
});
```

But I got this error

[image]

I am unable to understand where I am going wrong

Comment: I've never used that function or that calling convention but it appears that you failed to supply the second argument, namely "stats" that was expected.

Comment: @42- I am not clear abour the "stats" argument.. I included the library in `ocpu.seturl("//public.opencpu.org/ocpu/library/stats/R")
` in the setup. Where else did I miss out?

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/jzL22chm/

Comment: @Jeroen Thanks for the prompt reply. But is there any way we can get only the `p-value` for the t-test? In `R`, i know we can do it by `t.test(x,y)$p.value` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `ocpu.rpc` function is a shorthand that retrieves the output as JSON. However there is no JSON representation of a t.test object. Therefore you can use `ocpu.call` and retrieve e.g. the console output from the session [[fiddle]](http://jsfiddle.net/jzL22chm/):

```
var req = ocpu.call("t.test",{
    x : x,
    y : y
}, function(session){
  session.getConsole(function(outtxt){
      $("code").text(outtxt);
  });
});
```

If you want actual data (e.g p-value), I recommend you create an simple R package with a wrapper function that returns a list with data you are interested in:

```
my_ttest <- function(x, y){
  out <- t.test(x,y)
  list(
    n1 = length(x),
    n2 = length(y),
    p = out$p.value
  )
}
```

You will be able to call this function using `ocpu.rpc` as you did above, because the list can be mapped directly to JSON. Note that you can easily deploy your own package on the public demo server with the github webhook.

Comment: Hi thanks for the information. I created a package on github - now how can I call the function in the github package with opencpu?

Comment: got it - `ocpu.seturl("//public.opencpu.org/ocpu/github/githubusername/packagename/R")`